# DNS Tunnel using iodine in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, dns, iodine

I want to start DNS tunnel in Windows XP, so, after searching on Google, i found the [`iodine`](http://dev.kryo.se/iodine/wiki/IodineOnWindows) for windows. Reading ReadMe of iodine, show me to create `TAP` using [`openvpn`](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html). So, after install the `openvpn` and check the TAP option, it create me `TAP-Win32 Adapter V9` named `Local Area Connection 3`. So, i start to execute the iodine and face the problem as below :

```
C:\iodine.exe -d "Local Area Connection 3" abc.ab
Opening device Local Area Connection 3
Opened UDP socket
Opened UDP socket
Opened UDP socket
Sending DNS queries for abc.ab to 192.168.1.1
Autodetecting DNS query type (use -T to override)
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
.Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist

No suitable DNS query type found. Are you connected to a network?
If you expect very long roundtrip delay, use -T explictitly.
(Also, connecting to an "ancient" version of iodined won't work.)
```

What thing is wrong ? How can i use `iodine` to dns tunnel in windows ? Or, if there are other programs to dns tunnel, please help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you had any luck?

if I understand correctly you dont have to use option "-d" only if you use more than one TUN/TAP driver.

Than you have to give a name or remember it's name and use the option "-d"
I have only one TUN/TAP and iodine find it by itself.

I use only: C:\iodine\iodined -f 172.16.0.1 my-dns-forwarder-domain.com

Vaako

Comment: I am reviewing late answers, and for this I would suggest to move the questions/discussion to a comment, but other than that thanks for contributing your experience and knowledge.